# Why does this linked-list ordered insert segfault?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am working on a program that inserts into a linked-list in sorted order, but it keeps seg faulting, and I can't figure out why. I suspect it has something to do with the pointers, but I can't tell as these are still a little bit confusing to me at this point in my programming career. Also, I must keep the insert prototype the same. I can't change the node parameter into a double pointer. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node  *next;
};

int main ()
{
    struct node* first;  
    int temp,x,y;
    struct node *create (struct node *first);
    first = NULL;     
    void display (struct node *first);
    printf ("\n\nCreating a Linked List\n");
    printf ("\nEnter Element: ");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    y=x;
    while(y>0)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &x);
        insert_sorted_linked_list(first,x); 
        y--;
    }

    printf ("\nThe list after creation is: ");
    display (first);

    printf ("\nThe sorted list is: ");
    display (first);
    return(0);
}   /*END OF MAIN*/

insert_sorted_linked_list(struct node* head, int val)
{
    struct node* pCur;
    struct node* pNew = (struct node*) (malloc(sizeof(struct node)));

    pNew -> data = val;
    pNew ->next = NULL;
    pCur = head;

    if( pCur->data == NULL )
    {
        head->data = pNew->data;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else if (pNew->data  <   pCur->data)
    {
        pNew ->next = pCur ;
        head = pNew;
    }
}

void display (struct node *first)
{   struct node *save;         /*OR sort *save     */
    if (first == NULL)
        printf ("\nList is empty");
    else
    {  save = first;
        while (save != NULL)
        {   printf ("-> %d ", save->data);
            save = save->next;
        }
        getch();
    }
    return;
}
```

EDIT: Changed main to int. The debugger doesn't like the lines:

struct node* pNew = (struct node*) (malloc(sizeof(struct node)));

if( pCur->data == NULL )

Not sure what is wrong though.

**EDIT 2:**

I decided i wasn't going to get it working the original way he ask for it before tomorrow morning, so I went a modified version posted here. That one didn't seg fault, but it turns out there was a logic error as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct s
{
    int data;
    struct s  *next;
}node;


void insert_sorted_linked_list(node **head, int val);
void display (node **first);
void freeList(node **first);

int main ()
{
    node* first;
    int x,y;

    first = NULL;

    printf ("\n\nCreating a Linked List\n");
    printf ("\nEnter number of elements: ");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    y=x;
    while(y>0)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &x);
        insert_sorted_linked_list(&first,x);
        y--;
    }
    printf ("\nThe sorted list is: ");
    display (&first);
    freeList(&first);
    return 0;
}

void insert_sorted_linked_list(node **head, int val)
{
    node* pCur;
    node* pNew = (node*) (malloc(sizeof(node)));
    pNew->data = val;
    pNew->next = NULL;
    pCur = (*head);

    if( pCur == NULL )
    {
        (*head) = pNew;
    }
    else if(pNew->data  <   pCur->data)
    {
        pNew->next = pCur;
        (*head) = pNew;
    }
    else
    {
    while(pCur->next!=NULL && pNew->data  >  pCur->next->data)
        pCur = pCur->next;
    pNew->next = pCur->next;
    pCur->next = pNew;
    }
}


void display (node **first)
{
    node *lisprint;         /*OR sort *lisprint     */
    if (*first == NULL)
    printf ("\nList is empty");
    else
    {
        lisprint = *first;
        while (lisprint != NULL)
        {
            printf ("-> %d ", lisprint->data);
            lisprint = lisprint->next;
        }
        getch();
    }
}   /*END OF FUNCTION DISPLAY*/

void freeList(node **first)
{
    node *i;
    i = *first;
    while(i !=NULL)
    {
        (*first) = (*first)->next;
        free(i);
        i = *first;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the formatting itself would be enough for a segfault.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.  If you're on Linux, try GDB.  It will tell you the exact line where the segfault occurs.

Comment: And **`int`** `main()`. A-void `void`.

Comment: Your main error is between the 19 lines of code in the insert function, an access violation dereferencing a NULL pointer. I could say which one and why, but I've already put more effort into this than you have.

Comment: "I must keep the insert prototype the same. I can't change the node parameter into a double pointer. Thanks!" **Can I?** Seriously, if you can't change the prototype, including the return type (which isn't even legal in strict C99 as it requires a declared return type, yours is assumed `int` and never even specified), then then there is no way to change or send the head pointer except by external variable (read: global). Since you already know all this, and have likely rejected other attempts to change the prototype (or you wouldn't have brought it up), what exactly can help you with?

Comment: Correct, I have edited in at the bottom which lines it looks like are causing it. I'm not sure what is wrong though. But I have put lots of effort into this. I've been swapping out parts of this code for hours and tweaking different things in regards to others. I'm just a dumb programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Please properly format your code! It was a pain in the a** just to see where the error was!
As it is,

```
/*PROGRAM TO CREATE & THEN DISPLAY THE LINKED LIST IN SORTED FORM*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct s
{
    int data;
    struct s  *next;
}node; 
/* your declaration for typedef was incorrect. We use typedef in C for structures so   that we do not have to repeat struct s everytime. Using typedef, we can write node as we do in c++ */

void insert_sorted_linked_list(node **head, int val); /* do not need to return anything, as well as see the parameter. When we want to change a pointer, we pass the address to the pointer, as it results in passing by value */
void display (node **first); /* same here and below */
void freeList(node **first); /* if you don't do this, memory leak!!! */

int main ()
{
    node* first;  /*OR sort *first,*list,*pass  */
    int temp,x,y;

    first = NULL;      /*OR sort *create()  */

    printf ("\n\nCreating a Linked List\n");
    printf ("\nEnter number of elements: "); /* specify what you want the user to enter */
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    y=x;
    while(y>0)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &x);
        insert_sorted_linked_list(&first,x); /*CALLING CREATE FUNCTION, notice the &first*/
        y--;
    }
    printf ("\nThe list after creation is: ");
    display (&first);
    printf ("\nThe sorted list is: ");
    display (&first);
    freeList(&first);
    return 0;
}   /*END OF MAIN*/

void insert_sorted_linked_list(node **head, int val)
{
    node* pCur;
    node* pNew = (node*) (malloc(sizeof(node)));
    pNew->data = val;
    pNew->next = NULL;
    pCur = (*head);

    if( pCur == NULL )
    {
        (*head) = pNew;
    }
    else if (pNew->data  <   pCur->data)
    {
        pNew->next = pCur ;
        (*head) = pNew;
    }
}

/*DISPLAY FUNCTION*/
void display (node **first)
{
    node *save;         /*OR sort *save     */
    if (*first == NULL)
    printf ("\nList is empty");
    else
    {
        save = *first;
        while (save != NULL)
        {
            printf ("-> %d ", save->data);
            save = save->next;
        }
        getch();
    }
}   /*END OF FUNCTION DISPLAY*/

void freeList(node **first)
{
    node *i;
    i = *first;
    while(i !=NULL)
    {
        (*first) = (*first)->next;
        free(i);
        i = *first;
    }
}
```

Comment: While lovely, the OP has already stated modifying the interface for `insert_sorted_linked_list()` is not allowed: ***" I must keep the insert prototype the same. I can't change the node parameter into a double pointer."***

Comment: Ah, just saw it now! Well then,may Dennis Ritchie help him!

Comment: Yes, It's not my choice. When I looked online, I saw a lot of people doing it that way, but my professor specified I had to use that prototype. Idk if it is just amusing to him or what. Sorry for the formatting, I'm going to have to work on that. It's probably especially bad right now because I keep tearing it apart and rebuilding.